# Sequence not in Schreier space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

A finite subset $\{n_1 < n_2 < ... < n_k\} \subset N$ is called admissible if $k \leq n_1$. Let $E$ be the collection of admissible subset of $\mathbb{N}$

Define $S$ as the completion of finitely supported real sequences with respect to the norm

$$|x|_s:= \sup_{A \in E} \sum_{k \in A}|x_k|$$

where $x_k$ is the $k^{th}$ coordinate of $x$.

It's clear that $|x|_s = |x|_1$ (the $l^1$ norm) if $x$ has support in $E$. What is an example of a sequence that is in $l^2$, but not $S$?

Motivation is attempting to learn about Tsirelson's space from the book of Casazza and Shura

Comment: Isn't $y := (1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\dots)$ an example? Take any $\epsilon \in (0,\log 2)$. Suppose some finitely supported $x$ has $|y-x|_s < \epsilon$. If the support size of $x$ is $n$, then for the admissible set $A := \{n,n+1,\dots,2n-1\}$, we have $\epsilon > |y-x|_s \ge \sum_{k \in A} |y_k-x_k| = \sum_{k \in A} |y_k-0| = \log 2$, a contradiction.

Comment: @mathworker21 Could you elaborate on the last two equalities? I don't doubt that you're correct, I just don't see it

Comment: oops. by "support size is $n$", I meant "support contained in $\{1,\dots,n\}$". Actually, I need "support contained in $\{1,\dots,n-1\}$". With this correction, $k \in A$ implies $x_k = 0$. Finally, $\sum_{k \in A} y_k = \sum_{k=n}^{2n-1} \frac{1}{k} \approx \log 2$ (it's not actually an equality, but it's close enough).

Comment: ping ${}{}{}{}{}$